# MySQL Get AVR and save in New field

Tags: php, mysql

Hello I have this problem and can't find a solution:
I have 4 tables with same structure for example as follows:

1. Table 1: Result
2. Table 2: Store 1
3. Table 3: Store 2
4. Table 4: Store 3

   - Tables fields: ID - Code - Name - Value

I need a query to read the "Value" for each specific record from tables (Store 1 - Store 2 - Store 3) and calculate the average and save it in table (Result)...
and go on for the next record until it's done.

Note: I'm using PHP and MySQL...

Thanks in advanced...

```
SELECT
    result.id,
    result.`code`,
    result.`name`,
    result.value,
    term1.value,
    term2.value,
    term3.value
FROM result
INNER JOIN store1 ON result.`code` = store1.`code`
INNER JOIN store2 ON result.`code` = store2.`code`
INNER JOIN store3 ON result.`code` = store3.`code`
WHERE result.`code` = 123456
ORDER BY result.serial ASC
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I'm trying Navicat to build a query but no success with this issue in particular.

Comment: The question is a bit unclear, at least to me. Could you share some sample data and the answer you're trying to get?

Comment: Then share some code with us. There are a lot of knowledgeable people here that can point you in the right direction.

Comment: I combined the three tables in one query to see the result and it works:

Comment: SELECT
result.id,
result.`code`,
result.`name`,
result.value,
term1.value,
term2.value,
term3.value
FROM
result
INNER JOIN store1 ON result.`code` = store1.`code`
INNER JOIN store2 ON result.`code` = store2.`code`
INNER JOIN store3 ON result.`code` = store3.`code`
WHERE
result.`code` = 123456
ORDER BY
result.serial ASC

Comment: Don't put code in comments, update the question.

Comment: Ok this is my first use here... thanks for the hint...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The average is just the sum of the values divided by the number of values (3), this is grade school arithmetic.

```
UPDATE result AS r
JOIN store1 AS s1 ON s1.code = r.code
JOIN store2 AS s2 ON s2.code = r.code
JOIN store3 AS s3 ON s3.code = r.code
SET r.value = (s1.value+s2.value+s3.value)/3
```

To do lots of columns, you can generate the SQL in PHP:

```
$cols = array('col1', 'col2', 'col3', ...);
$sets = implode(', ', array_map(function($col) {
    return "r.$col = (s1.$col + s2.$col + s3.$col)/3";
}, $cols));
$sql = "UPDATE result AS r
        JOIN store1 AS s1 ON s1.code = r.code
        JOIN store2 AS s2 ON s2.code = r.code
        JOIN store3 AS s3 ON s3.code = r.code
        SET $sets";
```

If you're using PHP before 5.3.0, you can define a named function to call it with `array_map`

```
function make_assignment($col) {
    return "r.$col = (s1.$col + s2.$col + s3.$col)/3";
}
$sets = implode(', ', array_map('make_assignment', $cols));
```

Comment: [SQL] UPDATE result AS r
JOIN store1 AS s1 ON s1.code = r.code
JOIN store2 AS s2 ON s2.code = r.code
JOIN store3 AS s3 ON s3.code = r.code
SET r.value = (s1.value+s2.value+s3.value)/3

Affected rows: 302
Time: 0.297ms

Comment: can we modify the code to work on all fields as wildcard fields because I have about 163 fields with different names.

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how to generate the SQL dynamically using PHP.

Comment: Thanks again @Barmar for your respond... I face this error and can't go around it: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION, expecting ')' in D:\server\htdocs\store2015\index.php on line 15...    in the code is it array_map(function($cols) or $col... both didn't work with me...

Comment: What version of PHP are you using? Anonymous functions were added in 5.3.0. If you're older than that, you need to use `create_function`.

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how to do it if you're using an old PHP version.

Comment: This didn't work too on my php 5.2.6, so I upgraded to 5.5.1 on my other PC and still the old code can't save the results in the field but it runs without any error...

Comment: If you `echo $sql` and then execute it by hand, does it work?

Comment: I added mysql_error(); >> and the result was: No database selected... while the connection is OK

Comment: You forgot to call `mysql_select_db()` after `mysql_open()`. That's totally unrelated to this.

Answer (score 0):

You can create views in MySQL for this. Then there will not need any for this. View is a virtual table. On every change in any table it will automatically updated. You don't need any query

```
create view result as select t1.code as code,(t1.value+t2.value+t3.value)/3 as value from `testcake`.`test1` as t1 JOIN `testcake`.`test2` as t2 ON t1.code = t2.code JOIN `testcake`.`test3` as t3 ON t1.code = t3.code
```

Comment: Can't see the advantage in views, since it can't save with multiple fields with same name... while query did it